# .htaccess: how to remove Cache-Control's "max-age"?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

In the header response, I want to remove Cache-Control's "max-age"? I don't want to completely unset Cache-Control, though -- just want to get rid of max-age. So the following would be wrong:

Header unset Cache-Control

I think there is a way to do this using "edit" instead of "unset". However, I'm not sure how to use "edit".

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
Header edit Cache-Control ^(.*)max-age=(\d+)(.*)$ \1\3
```

This should remove the 'max-age= from the Cache-Control header.

Comment: Marco, I want to get rid of max-age, not keep it. I assume that is Perl regex. Would this be correct: `^(.*)(max-age=\d+,? )(.*)$/$1$3/ig`

Comment: It's a regular expression, yes, and I was wrong in that I put the wrong backreference; it's not Perl, however; take a look at mod_headers documentation, there is a little sample there. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Marco, this is from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/glossary.html#regex: "Apache uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions provided by the PCRE library." What is your reference that says it is not Perl?

Comment: As far as I can tell,  ^(.*)(max-age=\d+,? )(.*)$/$1$3/ig is not a regular expression, it is the perl syntax to make a search & replace using the regular expression ^(.*)(max-age=\d+,? )(.*)$. If you look at the syntax of the Header directive in the mod_headers, you can see that  it states: "For edit there is both a value argument which is a regular expression, and an additional replacement string." http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header

Answer (score 0):

Set it with different value:

```
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, ..."
```

It will replace the previous header.

Comment: Setting it to a different value is not an option. There are too many resources with too many different Cache-Controls. Basically, the only thing they have in common is that I want to remove max-age.